# PS Moving from ID and messeageID

Tags: powershell, csv

My script takes a CSV file, replaces some words and makes a new CSV file. It then moves the messages to a folder.

But now I'm trying to improve the script, I want it to look at 2 columns.

- Column 1 `ID` (1-40)
- Column 2 `messageID`

I'm trying to tell the script if the `ID` is `1`, it goes to folder `1`, if the `ID` is `2` the email goes to folder `2`, and so on. But can't seem to get it working.

```
import-csv c:\Report.csv | Select Mapi-Smtp-Message-Id | export-Csv -Path c:\messageid.csv

(Get-Content 'c:\temp\messageid.csv' | Select-Object -Skip 1) -replace "Mapi-Smtp-Message-Id", "messageID" | Set-Content 'c:\messageid.csv'

$MailboxName = "test@test.com"
$messageIds = Import-Csv -Path c:\messageid.csv |
    Select -expandproperty MessageId
    Select -expandproperty id

Connect-EXRMailbox -MailboxName $MailboxName
ForEach ($MessageId in $messageIds){
    $TargetFolder = "\inbox\folder1"
    Find-EXRMessageFromMessageId -MailboxName $MailboxName -MessageId $MessageId | ForEach-Object{
        Move-EXRMessage -MailboxName $MailboxName -ItemURI $_.ItemRESTURI -TargetFolderPath $TargetFolder
        Write-Host ("Moved Message " + $_.Subject + " to " + $TargetFolder)
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say its "not working", what is happening? Do you get an error, does it do nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$messages = Import-Csv -Path c:\messageid.csv

# Gives us a list of properties of your $messages object
$messages | Get-Member
```

I'm assuming one of the columns in your CSV is called `id` as you hinted in your question

```
foreach ($message in $messages) {
    $messageId = $message.MessageId
    $id = $message.id

    $TargetFolder = "\inbox\folder$id"

    Find-EXRMessageFromMessageId -MailboxName $MailboxName -MessageId $messageId |
        ForEach-Object {
            Move-EXRMessage -MailboxName $MailboxName -ItemURI $_.ItemRESTURI -TargetFolderPath $TargetFolder
            Write-Host "Moved Message $($_.Subject) to $TargetFolder"
        }
    }
}
```